# FastAPI: Mounting sub application ERROR 404 NOT FOUND

Tags: python, routes, http-status-code-404, fastapi, endpoint

I would like to set up sub applications in my FastAPI project. I have my root file which contains the configuration and a "routes" folder where my routes are organized in different files.

main.py

```py
app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/app")
def read_main():
    return {"message": "Hello World from main app"}


subapi = FastAPI()


@subapi.get("/sub")
def read_sub():
    return {"message": "Hello World from sub API"}


app.mount("/subapi", subapi)
```

This works, I have access to the FastAPI docs `localhot:8000/docs` and `localhost:8000/subapi` with my respective routes.

However, when I call a route in my file routes/session.py

```py
from app.main import subapi

@subapi.post(/session)
```

this route `/session` does not appear in the doc and when I test with curl I get a `404` error.

Am I forced to put all my controllers in my `main.py` file?

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Are you actually importing `routes/session.py` anywhere? i.e. does the code get run? Remember that code doesn't magically run in any file unless you're actually importing the file. Are you opening the docs under `/subapi/docs`?

Comment: No it's true I didn't import it in my main.py file but how can I import it since I don't use include_router?
Yes I have access /subapi/docs

Comment: `import projectname.subapi` - which will have to be after you've defined subapi in app.py in your example. But a better layout would be to declare `subapi = FastAPI()` in your `subapi.py` file, then import `subapi` from `projectname.subapi` and mount it in your app.py - that would avoid the circular dependency.